# How to fetch specific object from XML via $GET (JavaScript, Zjax, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I'm trying to fetch specific data from an API using GET but the output that I'm getting is 'Undefined'.

I don't know how to fetch a specific object ('low' and 'high' in this case)

here is my code:

```js
$.get('https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/exchange/ticker', function(object) {
  document.querySelector('#coinsecureBuy').innerHTML = object.low;
  document.querySelector('#coinsecureSell').innerHTML = object.high;
}, 'xml');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coinsecureBuy"></div>
<div id="coinsecureSell"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api supports JSON so use it

```
$.get('https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/exchange/ticker', function(o) {
  console.log(o.message.low);
  console.log(o.message.high);
});
```

Comment: @ManuelPitno You need to implement [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy. But this is on the server side.

Comment: No this is a security issues. What you can do is have a local proxy for the service on your backend.